# Body in uniform motion

Tags: kinematics, velocity, definition, speed

A body is said to be in uniform motion when it covers equal distances within equal time intervals. So that means at constant speed. However constant velocity also seems to be correct. So if one is faced with a question with both options, which would be best?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of uniform motion does not say anything about direction. This means that motion with a constant speed but not constant direction, it can be uniform.

Answer (score 1):

The definition is right, it's "equal distance at equal time", so it means constant speed, not constant velocity, since velocity is vector quantity.

The classification of motions is based on the properties of the velocity $\vec v = \vec v(t)$. If its absolute value is constant (the speed), then the motion is called uniform, otherwise it's nonuniform. If the direction is not changing in time, then it's called linear, otherwise non-linear or curved.

Now you can combine it into special types of motions:

- Uniform linear motion: Motion where direction and absolute value of velocity are not changing, that means $\vec a = 0$.
- Uniform motion on the circle: Special case of non-linear motions, where absolute value is constant $|\vec v | = 0$, but the direction is changing, so it means $\vec v(t) = v\, \vec e(t)$, where $\vec e(t)$ is a unit vector $| \vec e(t) | = 1$ for all $t$. Though the acceleration can't be zero and it holds $\vec a = a\, \vec e_n$, where $a = \omega^2 r = v^2/r$ and $\vec e_n$ is a normal vector to the trajectory (pointing in the middle of the circle) as is shown in all basic lectures of classical mechanics.
- And many others...

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is a vector (has magnitude and direction), speed is a scalar (has only magnitude).

An object that is going around in a circle has constant speed, but not constant velocity. Faced with the question you asked, I would say "constant velocity" is the more correct requirement to have "uniform motion".

Answer (score 0):

If the body is in rectilinear motion then speed and velocity are constant.  An object moving in a perfect circle covers an equal distance in equal times. Speed is a constant but velocity is not because body accelerates. So you would need to know if the uniform motion is in a straight line or not. In both case speed is a constant but not necessarily velocity.